# Python Virtual Environment Batch File Execution failing on Windows and not giving correct result

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, gauge, getgauge

I have created the batch file to create python virtual environment and run the Gauge command but its failing.

**I want to create Virtual Environment then activate it and then i want to run last Gauge command**

- pip install virtualenv
- cd c:\pyrates
- mkdir TSU-Virtual-Environment
- cd TSU-Virtual-Environment
- python -m venv TSU-MINI-PROJECT
- timeout 5
- cmd /k "cd \d C:\Pyrates\TSU-Virtual-Environment\TSU-MINI-PROJECT\Scripts & activate.bat & timeout 5 & pip install -r requirements.txt & cd \d c:\Pyrates & gauge run --env Editor --tags 'wp_usersToCSV' specs"
- pause

---

### Error:

```
C:\Pyrates\scripts>pip install virtualenv
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (20.0.35)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs<2,>=1.4.3 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from virtualenv) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.0.0 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from virtualenv) (3.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: six<2,>=1.9.0 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from virtualenv) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.1 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from virtualenv) (0.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata<3,>=0.12; python_version < "3.8" in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from virtualenv) (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from importlib-metadata<3,>=0.12; python_version < "3.8"->virtualenv) (3.3.2)
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 20.2.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\python37\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

C:\Pyrates\scripts>cd c:\pyrates

c:\Pyrates>mkdir TSU-Virtual-Environment
A subdirectory or file TSU-Virtual-Environment already exists.

c:\Pyrates>cd TSU-Virtual-Environment

c:\Pyrates\TSU-Virtual-Environment>python -m venv TSU-MINI-PROJECT

c:\Pyrates\TSU-Virtual-Environment>timeout 5

Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...

c:\Pyrates\TSU-Virtual-Environment>cd TSU-MINI-PROJECT

c:\Pyrates\TSU-Virtual-Environment\TSU-MINI-PROJECT>timeout 5

Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...

c:\Pyrates\TSU-Virtual-Environment\TSU-MINI-PROJECT>cd Scripts

c:\Pyrates\TSU-Virtual-Environment\TSU-MINI-PROJECT\Scripts>timeout 5

Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...

c:\Pyrates\TSU-Virtual-Environment\TSU-MINI-PROJECT\Scripts>cmd /k "cd \d C:\Pyrates\TSU-Virtual-Environment\TSU-MINI-PROJECT\Scripts & activate.bat & timeout 5 & pip install -r requirements.txt & cd \d c:\Pyrates & gauge run --env Editor --tags 'wp_usersToCSV' specs"
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 20.2.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\pyrates\tsu-virtual-environment\tsu-mini-project\scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
Specs directory specs does not exists.

(TSU-MINI-PROJECT) c:\Pyrates\TSU-Virtual-Environment\TSU-MINI-PROJECT\Scripts>
```

Comment: Since you just made the directory, you need to move the requirements.txt into the directory before running `pip install -r requirements.txt` after that it should be able to runge the guage command if its installed properly.

Comment: Thing is that when activate command get executed the current batch window get closed

Comment: - pip install virtualenv 
- cd c:\pyrates
- mkdir TSU-Virtual-Environment
- cd TSU-Virtual-Environment
- python -m venv TSU-MINI-PROJECT
- cd TSU-MINI-PROJECT
- cd Scripts
- activate.bat
- pip install -r c:\Pyrates\requirements.txt
- gauge run --env Editor --tags 'wp_usersToCSV' specs
pause

Comment: How can i integrate this into jenkins where i create Virtual Env First then i install required Libraries and then I execute Gauge command